# AttributeError: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'A1'

Tags: python

df dataset

```
custno       A1         A2

100001      aaa     bbb

100002      aaa     aaa

100003      bbb     aaa

100004       bbb     bbb
```

when I type in Python like below,

```
df.groupby(df.index.A1, df.index.A2).count()
```

---

error message is :

> AttributeError: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'A1'

How can I fix like these errors?

(dtype : A1 - object, A2 - object)

Comment: What was the expected result?

Answer (score 2):

Try following the docs for [DataFrame.groupby()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

```
data.groupby(['A1', 'A2'])
```

In your example you are trying to access each Series as an attribute of the index, which they are not.

Comment: I found the solution.

                  df.groupby(df.index.A1.apply(str), df.index.A2.apply(str)).count()        

^^;;